# How to know if a remote linux machine has booted?

Tags: networking, boot, network-shares

I have a Windows development machine, and a Linux target on a company network. After booting the target board, how do i learn if it has booted up ? `ping` `dig` `host` `nslookup` utilities with target name do not resolve the IP address and hence do not reply. The board has Busy box utilities only.

I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/281542/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-unix-linux-machine-whose-name-i-know) post, but the problem still stands.

Comment: You need to add some more bits of information: do you have remote access (via ssh, snmp, other) to that box? does it have an static IP or dynamic? if the former, don't need to resolve, just add it to your /etc/hosts file; if the latter, is the DHCP server under your control?

Comment: No static IP, no control over DHCP, the device has sshd running. I want to get rid of polling IP address over COM port every time the target board reboots.

Comment: So basically, you don't know the GNU/Linux target's IP beforehand?

Comment: Right I do not know the IP, but the hostname.

Comment: But you also said you can't resolve the name to its IP address, so basically that means you can't locate the machine

Comment: Correct. so do we see a workaround for this ? Or we are stuck for our inability to link IP address to any other attribute ?

Comment: You could try to locate the device at layer 2, if you happen to know the MAC address, and if the device attempts some kind of TCP/IP communication; but this involves controlling a switch/router, depending on your network topology

Comment: Thank you. I know the mac-ad but do not see myself going to layer 2.